# JAXB does not parse .xsd as intended. C# auto generation from same file does

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xsd

I am having some trouble with the way JAXB currently generates java objects from .xsd files. Below I have a code snippet from a .xsd file I am using. The intent of this code is that it will have a list of LogicalDevices which are objects that contain various information.

```
                        <xs:element name="LogicalDeviceList">
                            <xs:annotation>
                                <xs:documentation>List of all LogicalDevices currently added for the application</xs:documentation>
                            </xs:annotation>
                            <xs:complexType>
                                <xs:sequence>
                                    <xs:element name="LogicalDevice" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                        <xs:annotation>
                                            <xs:documentation>An added logical device</xs:documentation>
                                        </xs:annotation>
                                        <xs:complexType>
                                            <xs:attribute name="DeviceDefinitionId" use="required">
                                                <xs:annotation>
                                                    <xs:documentation>The DeviceDefinitionId of the Logical device</xs:documentation>
  .......... Other LogicalDevice Information
```

Currently the JAXB parser creates an object where the LogicalDeviceList isn't a list of LogicalDevices, and the LogicDevice returns a list of DeviceDefinitionIds.

As the XML I am receiving and unmarshaling cannot change in anyway, is there a way to fix this problem? Is it as simple as changing the .xsd file to read as such

UPDATE: The modification below does not work. 5-24-2013

```
                        <xs:element name="LogicalDeviceList" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                            <xs:annotation>
                                <xs:documentation>List of all LogicalDevices currently added for the application</xs:documentation>
                            </xs:annotation>
                            <xs:complexType>
                                <xs:sequence>
                                    <xs:element name="LogicalDevice">
                                        <xs:annotation>
                                            <xs:documentation>An added logical device</xs:documentation>
                                        </xs:annotation>
                                        <xs:complexType>
                                            <xs:attribute name="DeviceDefinitionId" use="required">
                                                <xs:annotation>
                                                    <xs:documentation>The DeviceDefinitionId of the Logical device</xs:documentation>
```

If so, why does the C# .xsd parser generate objects and list from the original xsd as intended and JAXB does not.

Comment: Because the modification does not work is there another option other than JAXB that will parse the .xsd file and create the object as intended.

Comment: It is hard to diagnose from the partial schema, can you post more?  I'm the EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy) lead, feel free to contact me with the following link:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/p/contact_01.html

Comment: Thank you for the response Blaise, I have emailed you as requested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the XML schema fragment:

```
<xs:element name="LogicalDeviceList">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation>List of all LogicalDevices currently added for the application</xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="LogicalDevice" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation>An added logical device</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:attribute name="DeviceDefinitionId" use="required">
                        <xs:annotation>
                            <xs:documentation>The DeviceDefinitionId of the Logical device</xs:documentation>
                        ...
```

You are going to get a class structure like the following where the `LogicalDeviceList` class has a collection of `LogicalDevice` instances.

```
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    @XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
        "logicalDevice"
    })
    public static class LogicalDeviceList {

        @XmlElement(name = "LogicalDevice")
        protected List<LogicalDeviceList.LogicalDevice> logicalDevice;
```

JAXB may not exactly match what is generated by C#, but it is a perfectly acceptable representation of the XML schema.